# g++ links library ld doesn't

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, ld

I would like to know why

```
g++ test1.o test2.o -o test.x -lgtk-x11-2.0
```

works, while

```
ld 'r test1.o test2.o -o test.o -lgtk-x11-2.0
```

gives:

```
ld: cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0
```

unless I explicitly include the path adding `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

I tried everything adding the path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or to `ld.so.conf` but nothing works and I cannot explain myself the difference between the two calls.

On the manual of ld it is specified:

> The default set of paths searched (without being specified with `-L') depends on which emulation mode ld is using, and in some cases also on how it was configured

but trying different emulations (by using -m*emulation*) imply segfaulting (probably since the default emulation elf_i386, is the right one).

Can you help me shed light on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are curious about the paths used by `ld`

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH
```

usually you don't want to use `ld` explicitly for linking, it's probably better to perform every task with `gcc` alone, and you should prefer the latter over the former.

If you want to know more about `gcc` settings

```
gcc -dumpspecs
```

gives you a taste of what it's like to take a look at the internals of `gcc`, you will probably end up taking a look at the `gcc` manual if you are serious about this, but I don't think that is something worth doing just for the sake of it.

Settings defined at the time when `gcc` was compiled can be important too, so you should also learn how to compile `gcc` from source if you really want to grasp how the internals work.

tl;dr

Just use `gcc` for both compiling and linking, other options are probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc -print-search-dirs` (or `g++`) displays the library search path used by the compiler; `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` is likely built in. This option is passed to the linker by gcc, but not built in to the linker.

Try adding `-v` : `g++ -v test1.o test2.o -o test.x -lgtk-x11-2.0`
to see how the linker is invoked.